# What are the full names of the two sufyans in this oral chain: Imam Ahmad < Wakee < Sufyan and Abdurrahman < Sufyan < Abi Zubayr < Jabir < The Prophet

Tags: hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

In the book titled:

> مسند أحمد - ط الرسالة 
> **[ [Maktaba Shamela](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/10770) ]**

I found this chain quoted:

> Wakee' < Sufyan and Abdurrhaman < Sufyan < Abi Zubayr < Jabir < The Messenger of Allah 
> **[ [Maktaba Shamela](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/10770) ]**

and Imam Ahmad would of course be transmitting from Wakee'.

My question is, what are the full names of the two Sufyans mentioned in this Chain?

My guess is the second sufyan is "Sufyan Ibn Uyaynah" as he lived earlier. But I don't know about the first sufyan.

Comment: If you read the footnote on the next page it says that it is Sufyan al-Thawri. I would assume that there is only one Sufyan and Wakee' and Abdur Rahman narrate from him.

Comment: thank you :DDDDDDDDD